# Question about the [PXDimension] attribute

Tags: acumatica

If I set up my own segmented key ID to be used with a custom DAC's identity field, Do I need anything else other than the [PXDimension] attribute on that DAC field to implement the enforcement of that segment setup?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would have to define your custom field with the [PXDimensionSelector] attribute.
When this attribute is used, the first parameter should be the dimension name (defined in the Segmented Keys page - CS202000), followed by the ID value (this is the value persisted in the DB), and then the CD value (this is the user-friendly value).

For instance, the Item Class Dimension selector can be defined like this:

```
  [PXDimensionSelector(INItemClass.Dimension, 
                typeof(Search<INItemClass.itemClassID, Where<INItemClass.stkItem, Equal<False>>>), typeof(INItemClass.itemClassCD), DescriptionField = typeof(INItemClass.descr))]
```

When the value is then added to the UI, the framework will recognize the Dimension-selector attribute and it will create it as a **PXSegmentMask** field instead of a regular **PXSelector**

Comment: Question - can I use just a CD (string field) with a dimension selector, or is it necessary to have the ID/CD arrangement?

Comment: typically the ID/CD arrangement is preferable. But I don't see why it would not work using the CD value only.

Comment: Thanks much, Fernando!